# Multiple values in variable and need to check IF condition for each value

Tags: function, db2

I'm writing DB2 stored procedure. This stored procedure will be called using .ksh script.

I was stuck in checking IF condition.

`VARIABLE = 'test1,test3,test8,......testn'` The variable's datatype is `varchar`

```
IF VARIABLE = 'test1'
THEN
--PRINT TEST1 HERE;
END IF;

IF VARIABLE = 'test8'
THEN
--PRINT TEST8 HERE;
END IF;
```

could you please help me to achieve this?

Comment: Is that intended to be SQL or ksh script?

Comment: intended to be stored procedure which have sql statements and that stored procedure will be called by ksh

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to be asking this at dba.stackexchange.com. Have you gotten the SQL working and you're trying to call it with KSH, or are you still working on the SQL side?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF LOCATE(',test1,', ','||VARIABLE||',')<>0 THEN
THEN
--PRINT TEST1 HERE;
END IF;
```